# Is there any way that creates a standalone compiled python file for Linux?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote a simple hello world with *python 3.8* on *Ubuntu 20.04* and compiled it using *pyinstaller*.

Executable file run perfectly on my computer but when I run it on computer with other *Ubuntu* (16.04, 18.04 or 20.04) I got errors.

I'm using *staticx* to bind all dependencies to the file but there is no difference.

Errors messages:

> in 20.04: "segmentation fault (core dumped)"
>
> in 16.04: "[6680] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIuLupkg/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIuLupkg/libpython3.8.so.1.0)"

Comment: Let me suggest a simple workaround: build your standalone executable on the oldest platform you want to support. It should work and be forward-compatible.